# jQuery selection problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, x3d

was just wondering if you could help.

I have the following bit of code:

```
<transform DEF='veyron_colour_change' rotation='0.2815 -0.6785 0.6785 -3.69' scale='0.2107 0.2107 0.2107' translation='-2.291 26.33 19.26'>
  <shape>
    <appearance>
      <material ambientIntensity='1' diffuseColor='1 0.1255 0.1255' shininess='0.3825' specularColor='1.215 1.215 1.215'></material>
    </appearance>
    <indexedFaceSet creaseAngle='1' DEF='veyron_colour_change-FACES'...
```

I am trying to select the material element using jQuery in order to change the diffuseColor attribute. The code im trying to do this with is:

```
$('[DEF="veyron_colour_change"]').next('[diffuseColor]').attr('diffuseColor', '0.2118 0.1569 0.9333');
```

But it isnt working. any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `.find()` not `.next()`:

```
$('[DEF="veyron_colour_change"]').find('[diffuseColor]').attr('diffuseColor', '0.2118 0.1569 0.9333');
```

The element with that attribute (in this case, `<material />`) is a descendant of the `<transform />` element, so you use `.find()` to locate it. `.next()` means it comes *after* the element rather than occurring *inside* it.